# import imdb movie information into a custom meta box wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

rather than

```
echo "Writer: ".$Response['Writer'].
```

How would I code it so that it would populate a custom taxonomy named writerBox.

and

```
echo "Plot: ".$Response['Plot'].
```

into a custom custom metabox named plotBox.